# Date validation boolean error in Python?

Tags: python

I decided to give Python a whirl and am building a fake data validator. Seems like my code is always outputting error, and I think it's because of my misuse of the boolean.

```
'''
Date_Validation_Testing
'''
year_conditional = False
day_conditional = False

def valid_year(year):
    if (year.isdigit()):
        year = int(year)
        if (year < 2030 and year > 1899):
            year_conditional = True
            return year_conditional


def valid_day(day):
    if (day.isdigit()):
        day = int(day)
        if (day <= 31 and day > 0):
            day_conditional = True
            return day_conditional


day = raw_input("Enter a day: ")
year = raw_input("Enter a year: ")

valid_day(day)
valid_year(year)


if (year_conditional and day_conditional):
    print("woooo!") 
else:
    print("boooo!")
```

Comment: Could you perhaps provide the error traceback?

Comment: It is just immediately jumping to my else statement.

Comment: Have you tested your `valid_...` functions? Do you know what they return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning the returned value. Your code should be

```
day_conditional = valid_day(day)
year_conditional = valid_year(year)
```

This is because of how namespaces work in python. In most programming languages, when a local variable is not found, it is looked for in the global namespace. In python though, if you want to change a global variable you have to first declare it like so:

```
def valid_day(day):
    global day_conditional
    ...
```

However, this is often considered bad practice. It's much more convenient and efficient to avoid this by using, for example, return.

Convenient - because it's clear in the code when and how a global variable is changed, without reading through the function declarations.

Efficient - because of how stacks and global variables work. Accessing a global variable usually takes a bit longer than accessing a local one.

Answer (score 2):

Your `valid_day` and `valid_year` functions are returning a value, but you're never assigning it to anything. You've named the validation `day_conditional` and `year_conditional` the same as in your root level, but they're not the same thing because they're in different scopes.

You have two options, one vastly better than the other. The worse option is to define `global day_conditional` in `valid_day` and `global year_conditional` in `valid_year`. Then you can ignore the `return` calls because it will modify the conditionals you've already built.

What you REALLY should do is:

```
day_conditional = valid_day(day)
year_conditional = valid_year(year)
```

instead of

```
valid_day(day)
valid_year(year)
```

When you call `day_conditional = valid_day(day)`, it will set `day_conditional` to whatever `valid_day` returns.

Comment: So, previously, I read about global variable, which I'm assuming is the similar way of modifying private instance variables in Java, correct? Why is that a worse option?

Comment: @Simplex because it's violating encapsulation theory. In this case there's no reason to have `day_conditional` accessible to any object but your module. There are small but notable exceptions to the "don't use globals" rule, but unless it's strictly necessary, stay away.

Comment: @Simplex I'm not familiar with Java, but the `global` keyword is used in a function to tell the function "Hey, any time you see this variable, we're talking about the one on the global scope." Because of that, `global day_conditional` would force `valid_day` to think of the global scoped `day_conditional` you initialized to `False` at the top of your script, and `day_conditional = False` would change that variable. However since you don't need to know its value anywhere inside the function it's better to return the value you want to give it and change it via assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **global** keyword.
You have to declare the varible global before to use it.
[Global Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

```
year_conditional= False
day_conditional= False
def valid_year(year):
    if (year.isdigit()):
        year = int(year)
        if (year < 2030 and year > 1899):
            global year_conditional
            year_conditional = True
            return year_conditional


def valid_day(day):
    if (day.isdigit()):
        day = int(day)
        if (day <= 31 and day > 0):
            global day_conditional
            day_conditional = True
            return day_conditional


day = raw_input("Enter a day: ")
year = raw_input("Enter a year: ")

valid_day(day)
valid_year(year)


if (year_conditional and day_conditional):
    print("woooo!") 
else:
    print("boooo!")
```